# how can i return the letter if it is not found in the dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to encrypt the file using a dictionary i want to print the corresponding value to the key, but some letters are not in the dictionary meaning that letter is what is needed to be printed

```
#opening the file
file = open("fileToEncrypt.txt", 'r')
#the dictionary 
CODE = {'A':')','a':'0','B':'(','b':'9','C':'*','c':'8',\
        'D':'&','d':'7','E':'^','e':'6','F':'%','f':'5',\
        'G':'$','g':'4','H':'#','h':'3','I':'@','i':'2',\
        'J':'!','j':'1','K':'Z','k':'z','L':'Y','l':'y',\
        'M':'X','m':'x','N':'W','n':'w','O':'V','o':'v',\
        'P':'U','p':'u','Q':'T','q':'t','R':'S','r':'s',\
        'S':'R','s':'r','T':'Q','t':'q','U':'P','u':'p',\
        'V':'O','v':'o','W':'N','w':'n','X':'M','x':'m',\
        'Y':'L','y':'l','Z':'K','z':'k','!':'J','1':'j',\
        '@':'I','2':'i','#':'H','3':'h','$':'G','4':'g',\
        '%':'F','5':'f','^':'E','6':'e','&':'D','7':'d',\
        '*':'C','8':'c','(':'B','9':'b',')':'A','0':'a',\
        ':':',',',':':','?':'.','.':'?','<':'>','>':'<',\
        "'":'"','"':"'",'+':'-','-':'+','=':';',';':'=',\
        '{':'[','[':'{','}':']',']':'}'}

for letter in file:
    if letter in CODE.keys():
        values = CODE.get(letter,"Not here")
        print(values)
```

the output would just print the default "Not here"

Comment: `CODE.get(letter, letter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the letters you must do a double for, since the first one iterates on the rows, and the second it will do on the letters.

```
#opening the file
file = open("fileToEncrypt.txt", 'r')
#the dictionary 
CODE = {'A':')','a':'0','B':'(','b':'9','C':'*','c':'8',\
        'D':'&','d':'7','E':'^','e':'6','F':'%','f':'5',\
        'G':'$','g':'4','H':'#','h':'3','I':'@','i':'2',\
        'J':'!','j':'1','K':'Z','k':'z','L':'Y','l':'y',\
        'M':'X','m':'x','N':'W','n':'w','O':'V','o':'v',\
        'P':'U','p':'u','Q':'T','q':'t','R':'S','r':'s',\
        'S':'R','s':'r','T':'Q','t':'q','U':'P','u':'p',\
        'V':'O','v':'o','W':'N','w':'n','X':'M','x':'m',\
        'Y':'L','y':'l','Z':'K','z':'k','!':'J','1':'j',\
        '@':'I','2':'i','#':'H','3':'h','$':'G','4':'g',\
        '%':'F','5':'f','^':'E','6':'e','&':'D','7':'d',\
        '*':'C','8':'c','(':'B','9':'b',')':'A','0':'a',\
        ':':',',',':':','?':'.','.':'?','<':'>','>':'<',\
        "'":'"','"':"'",'+':'-','-':'+','=':';',';':'=',\
        '{':'[','[':'{','}':']',']':'}'}

for row in file:
    for letter in row.strip():
        values = CODE.get(letter,"Not here")
        print(values)
```